How to periodize a rectangular pulse?
A new signal u3p(t) has to be generated from u3(t) through periodic extension with a period T = Ti.
u3p(t) has to be drawn from -Ti ≤ t ≤ 2Ti.

I have a graph of the resulting periodic function (see below) and I don't understand how it was done. It would be clearer if the original signal had only one rectangular pulse, but the presence of two pulses confuses me. Was the second pulse ignored?
Why do we start at -3/2 Ti and not -Ti?
Why did the distance between two rectangles become equal to the rectangle's width?


Hint: Use paper and pencil and graph paper to sketch the signals $u_3(t)$,  $u_3(t-T_i)$, and $u_3(t)+u_3(t-T_i)$, Notice how the righthand pulse of $u_3(t)$ which starts at $t=\frac{T_i}{4}$ and ends at $t=\frac{T_2}{2}$ joins up with the lefthand pulse of $u_3(t-T_i)$ which starts at $t=\frac{T_i}{2}$ and ends at $\frac{3T_i}{4}$ to make a single pulse of height $U_0$ which starts at $t=\frac{T_i}{4}$ and ends at $\frac{3T_i}{4}$, i.e. a width of $\frac{T_i}2$. We can do similar calculations with $u_3(t-2T_i)$ and with $u_3(t+T_i)$ to end up with the graph shown for $u_{3p}(t)$: a sequence of pulses of height $U_0$ and width $\frac{T_i}{2}$ repeating every $T = T_i$ time units with each pulse centered in its epoch $[kT, (k+1)T)$.
Heaven knows why the OP's teacher chose to use such awful notation as $T_i$ only to change it to the simpler $T$ at the very end.
